# How to force chrome to use the pac file in macos?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, proxy

I'm running on macos Mojave. Configuring the proxy, google chrome links me to the system network settings. In which I entered the file path to in the Automatic proxy configuration pac file. file:///Users/{username}/.pac.

The same file is working perfectly on firefox. Chrome seems to be ignoring it.

I tried to reapply the proxy setting using [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/343445/how-to-force-chrome-to-reload-proxy-configuration-file?rq=1)

Comment: I was looking for a solution myself.
Check my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/564741/add-a-proxy-to-a-particular-host-only-in-mac/1460681#1460681

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Contrary to the belief.](https://superuser.com/a/1068318/881406)

The `file:///..pac` format doesn't work. I ended uploading my pac file as a gist on github and supplying the raw link to the network tool.